# Is it safe to boost output voltage to the maximum limit?

Tags: voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit, boost

I'm going to be using the [MCP1640](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/devices.aspx?dDocName=en547080) for boosting one AA battery to 5.5V. However, its max output voltage is 5.5V. Will it be safe to boost the output to the maximum limit and not cause damage to the chip?

Thanks

Comment: I looked at the datasheet. I think it is OK to go to 5.5V, but the performance will probably be poor. In general, what you want to avoid is the "absolute maximum" ratings. In this case, the abs. max is 6.5V. The datasheet does not use the terminology "recommended operating range" but, basically, 5.5V is the top of the recommended operating range. Don't expect to get much current at that output Voltage, and don't expect efficiency much over 80%. Also, the available power will fall off dramatically as battery voltage declines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having done exactly this in the past, I can say with great confidence that this is fine. Efficiency isn't the best at the top end of output but it will work fine taking that into account.